# How to check if the value is numeric?

Tags: r, regex, decimal, numeric

Can someone help me modify the function below to check if a number is numeric?

```
# handy function that checks if something is numeric
check.numeric <- function(N){
  !length(grep("[^[:digit:]]", as.character(N)))
}

check.numeric(3243)
#TRUE
check.numeric("sdds")
#FALSE
check.numeric(3.14)
#FALSE
```

I want `check.numeric()` to return `TRUE` when it's a decimal like 3.14.

Comment: Why is `is.numeric` not sufficient...?

Comment: Oh haha I didn't know there was already a built-in R function that did that. thanks, that's exactly the function I need. I still need help though. see comment below

Comment: @joran the script I'm working on `is.numeric(x)` where `x` is assigned the value `x<- NA_real_` results in `TRUE`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you have two things to check: `is.numeric` and `is.na`.

Comment: I believe that is the point of `NA_real_` - to be simultaneously `NA` and numeric.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want a function like this:

```
f <- function(x) is.numeric(x) & !is.na(x)
```

Comment: that fixed the error thanks again (I'll give you the thumbs up) but now I'm getting a slightly unrelated error: `evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?`

Comment: @user1313954 No clue. You'll have to ask about that in a separate question. (But be sure to provide the relevant code and plenty of detail. Based on what you've shared so far, it would be literally impossible for anyone to help.)

Comment: @user1313954, did you call your function `is.numeric` and have it call the `is.numeric` function?  if so that would cause the infinite recursion as your function keeps calling itself.  Best would be to use a different name for your function, otherwise you could use the `::` notation to make sure that you call the correct version of `is.numeric`.

Comment: @GregSnow I did call the function `is.numeric` and have it call `is.numeric` function. I changed the function name back to `f` and compiled again but I'm still getting the same error. Can you remind me again how I would use the `::` notation to make sure I'm calling the correct version of `is.numeric`?

Comment: @user1313954, The `::` notation is just `base::is.numeric(x)`.  But your problem is probably that you still have the wrong version of `is.numeric` around to be called by the new function.  You need to delete it (`rm(is.numeric)`).

Comment: @GregSnow that was the problem. It just finished compiling. thanks Greg

Answer (score 15):

You could use `is.finite` to test whether the value is numeric and non-NA.  This will work for numeric, integer, and complex values (if both real/imaginary parts are finite).

```
> is.finite(NA)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(NaN)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(Inf)
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(1L)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite(1.0)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite("A")
[1] FALSE
> is.finite(pi)
[1] TRUE
> is.finite(1+0i)
[1] TRUE
```